# How change toolbar's text color according to my user input?

Tags: android

In my toolbar has a textView which is invisible by default. After user input something in my edittext, the textView should be visible to user. How to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

For your editText view, you can add a TextWatcher.

TextWatcher like this:

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            int vibility  = (TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence)) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;
            textView.setVisibility(vibility);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: You can create custom listener and give call back to respective fragment or activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length()>0){
                toolBarTextView.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
                toolBarTextView.setText("");
            }else {
                toolBarTextView.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
                toolBarTextView.setText(s.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```